# How to show all results of a list in jinja?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

this is my template:

```
{% for item in naa %} 
    <a href="post/{{item['id']}}/{{item['about']}}">{{item['about']}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

and flask:

```
cur.execute("SELECT post_id FROM favorites WHERE username = %s",[session['username']])
data=cur.fetchall()
naa = []
for row in data:
    pos_id = row["post_id"]
    cur.execute("SELECT* FROM posts WHERE id=%s ORDER BY created_at DESC",[pos_id])
    naa.append(cur.fetchall())
cur.close()
return render_template("favoritesm.html",naa = naa)
```

it's showing results but broken links like:

```
localhost/post//
```

so what's the problem and how to fix it?

*THANKS*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.fetchall() returns a [list of tuples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html). Therefore .append is creating a list of lists. I believe you want to use .extend instead.

```
naa.extend(cur.fetchall())
```

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252711/1106952) to [What is the difference between Python's list methods append and extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend)